# How to run an android app without stop

Tags: android

I recently built an android application that i need to run 24/24 7/7.
I thought about using web servers, so I bought KVM VPS WITH 2GB RAM AND 2 CPU CORES (Ubuntu). I tried to install Genymotion on it but it doesn't work, so I tried to use the androidx86 version on virtualbox and it works but it is very slow.
Now i am asking if there is a way to run an android application 24/24 on a server ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run an Android application on your computer and have it be fast, you'll need to use the x86_64 or x86 images.  Using an ARM or MIPS based image requires overhead since native instructions can't be run on an x86 computer.  Genymotion is good, but I find the new Android Emulator is really fast, and it's free.

I would check out the new Android Emulator and use an x86/x86_64 based image.  You can customize your image to provide extra disk space and RAM allocation to the system image for better performance.  I've had great luck getting it to run quickly and smoothly in recent builds.

Here is blog post and video from Google announcing the new and improved emulator at Android Dev Summit in December of 2015: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-studio-20-preview-android.html

Note: Please make sure you have the most up to date Android SDK for best performance and to make sure you have the version they talk about in the link.

Comment: I'm not running it on my computer i am using a vps :) and on vps it's very slow as long as it doesn't support acceleration so what im looking for now is a way or a provider that sells vps that run emulators smoothly i prefer genymotion

Comment: Get a faster VPS then.

Comment: Most vps don't support genymotion because as i said it requires kvm virtualization . Can you recommand a vps that can run android native emulator smoothly please ?